# Open new page in the same broswer window without affecting the browser history

Tags: javascript

The question is for IE7 only, because location.replace(strURL) seems to work file in all other major browsers.
I try to execute some analytics js and then redirect the users to the location of a resource (usually doc or pdf) they want to download.
The user opens a page containing the js code.
After the download is tracked the broswer should load the resurouce url using the following code by REPLACING the current page entry in the history with the resource url:

```
if (IE) {
            window.open(strURL,"_self", true); //doesn't work
            //window.open(strURL,"_self",undefined, true); //doesn't work
            return;
        }
```

This code creates entry in the history for the redirecting page.
I have tried using iframe on the same page but IE will pop up a security warning if the file is a *.doc

Any ideas?

Comment: You lost me at "The user opens...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid this in IE7 or not.  Perhaps a different approach is possible.  Inject the analytics js into the current page before redirecting, thereby avoiding the need to load another page altogether.  In this approach, you would create a new script tag and inject it into the head element.  The script will execute when it loads, do your analytics and then trigger the redirect for download as the last step (for instance).

```
function redirectWithAnalytics() {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'path/to/analytics.js';
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in my case. I don't know if a user has clicked on a download link until I make a trip to the database because the request goes through a common asset handler which serves requests for various files, including site images. So deciding whether to inject the tracking script will cost another trip to the server. Anyways, am I doing something wrong with the window.open method. I am not able to find anyone else with same or similar issue, which makes me think that I might be doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not make the src of the script the serverside script which does the database check and have it return the analytics code if appropriate, otherwise return an empty string or a call to some other function to notify the user that they didn't click a valid link?